# When does a browser logs a history?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, browser-history

Does a browser logs a history on url hit? or when all the resources of an html page are loaded?

In my page, few external links make my landing page load a little longer..though the html(view) page is rendered. Based on a condition check, angular js routes to the second page quickly, but the browser history log doesn't store the first page's entry. We have back button functionality enabled in our page. So when a user clicks on browser back button, it should show the first page. But instead, browser's home page is rendered.

I've already asked a similar question related to angular js here:

[Angular JS - How to force browser to log history for quick routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426395/angular-js-how-to-force-browser-to-log-history-for-quick-routing/29426661#29426661)

I'm unable to adopt both the solutions since we're not encouraging any third party scripts such as angular ui-router. Also, the second solution is not adoptable since after  $http.get('/someUrl') we need to delay for few seconds to call another service. If "someUrl" takes some 6 to 7 seconds, we need to know this delay beforehand (which is indefinite) to call another service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's **$location.replace()** did the magic at last.

Previously I was using **$location.url('/somepath')** which was only redirecting to my browser's home page instead of saving first page's history.

Answer (score 0):

AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows you to organize the parts of your interface into a state machine. Unlike the $route service in the Angular ngRoute module, which is organized around URL routes, UI-Router is organized around states, which may optionally have routes, as well as other behavior, attached.

States are bound to named, nested and parallel views, allowing you to powerfully manage your application's interface.

For more help refer this
[Angular JS - How to force browser to log history for quick routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426395/angular-js-how-to-force-browser-to-log-history-for-quick-routing)

Comment: Reena, this was answered in stack thread I gave above. I'm unable to use it. And, that's why I've asked for another solution other than third party  service.